# Android NDK, standalone build , Error not executable: magic 7F45 and/or not executable: magic 4c01

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

Im trying to compile a modified version of "su" super user , utility so I went along to android5.0 source on git, and got the "su.c" file.

**My actual device/hardware is a LeTV x500 phone running:**

- Android 5.0.2 ,**SDK 21**
- CPU architecture **AArch64** Processor rev 2
- Instruction set **arm64-v8a**.

I'm about the hardware data, because I have checked the manufacturers site & also used a 3rd party app to get the software/hardware info.

**Using cygwin shell:**

$ sh make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-21 --install-dir=/cygdrive
/c/users/anaim/ndk-standalone_arm64 --arch=arm64 --toolchain=aarch64-linux-andr
oid-4.9 --ndk-dir=/cygdrive/c/Users/anaim/android-ndk-r10e --system=windows-x86
_64

**Result:**

Copying prebuilt binaries...
Copying sysroot headers and libraries...
Copying c++ runtime headers and libraries...
Copying files to: /cygdrive/c/users/anaim/ndk-standalone_arm64
Cleaning up...
Done. command:

**Then I compiled my modified su.c:**

$ /cygdrive/c/Users/anaim/ndk-standalone_arm64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc -c
 su.c -o su -I/cygdrive/c/Users/anaim/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arc
h-arm/user/include

Then I pushed the su binary to the device path /local/data/tmp & issued chmod 777 against the su , but when I wanted to execute a got this error:

$ /data/local/tmp/su
/system/bin/sh: **/data/local/tmp/su: not executable: magic 7F45**

I tried using another toolchain with **--arch flag to set --arch=arm** but that gave me a slightly different error **/data/local/tmp/su: not executable: magic 4c01**.

Why are both standalone-toolchains arm & **arm64 (this should the correct one)** not able to to create the write binary for the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc -c` will create an object file, not an executable. Remove `-c` parameter from your command line.

Comment: @pelay, thanks that error seems to go away, that was silly copy & paste I overlooked. Now im getting "only position independent executables (PIE) are supported", any suggestions?

Comment: I fixed "only position independent executables (PIE) are supported" by adding -shared -fpic flags to the compile command , but niow when I run the su binary , I get "Segmentation fault" ???

Comment: You don't want `-shared`, it will create a library instead of executable (technically also executable but  with unresolved symbols). Remove it, and add `-l library` to your compiler flags until there won't be unresolved symbols anymore.